# Getting NSNumber from financial string

Tags: ios, swift, nsnumber

I have this extension to get finical string from `Double`

```
extension Double {
    static let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    var financialString: String? {
        
        Double.formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
        Double.formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
        Double.formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2
        
        if let result =  Double.formatter.string(for: self) {
            return result
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting 1,001.00 text value from 1001 which is right. One thing that I want to get 1001 back from 1,001.00 now.

Is there a way to get NSNumber from financial string?

Comment: just use number from string

Comment: In Formatter, there are always `string(for: Object) -> String`, and `object(from: String) -> Object?`, in case of `NumberFormatter`, it's `number(from: String) ) -> Number` See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/numberformatter/1408845-number

Comment: @LeoDabus works great! thanks I forget about this simple operation.

Comment: @MatrosovOleksandr make sure to set a fixed locale (usually en_US_POSIX) before setting the style.

Comment: got it thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could filter the string using a character set and only get the numbers and decimal point back.  Then convert that string to a Double.

```
let characterSet = Set(".0123456789")
Double("$1,001.00".filter(characterSet.contains))
```

Comment: This will not work for other decimal or grouping separators.

Comment: yea looks like this adding extra numbers after a dot for example 20.6 can be written as 20.59999 but any way if we say just about getting doubles it could work, but just with this not accuracy issue. NSNumber from string works like a Sharm. Thanks for answer any way